# How to include Mapael in Aurelia?

Tags: aurelia, mapael

I am new to programming and need to include one of `Mapael's maps` to my code.

But I don't exactly know how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the head portion of your code:

```
<script src="js/jquery.mapael.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

Just change the location where the javascript file is located.

Then you can simply use the class likewise:

```
<div class="mapcontainer">
    <div class="map">
    </div>
</div>
```

Refer to the code of the examples [here](https://www.vincentbroute.fr/mapael/#examples), where you can actually see how it is implemented.

Comment: Thank you. How about JS code? To have hovering options.

Comment: If you're talking about a legend being shown when you hover over a state showing it's information, check this example, it's pretty straight-forward: https://rawgit.com/neveldo/jQuery-Mapael/2.2.0/examples/basic/legend_areas.html ?

Comment: What you are looking for is the 'tooltip' property within each area. If my answer was helpful, please mark the answer as solved.